# Find R1 in voltage divider, based on current and R2

Tags: voltage, current, resistors

This is a picture of my analysis on this circuit. although i've spent hours and hours trying to figure out how to get R1 myself (which is 54 Ohm's according to the book), i can not figure out how to Do it, and how this circuit works.

I was hoping someone could light me up and explain this.

[image: Find R1]

Comment: I got it right after i found the right way of thinking (cause that was the reason why i didnt figure this out). i got rather confused by the answers, but in the end it went well, if one choose to answer, one should have time to explain with the respect of the unknowing.

Answer (score 1):

With 50mA flowing thru the diode, it will drop about 0.7 volts. This means the voltage on the anode with respect to the negative ends of the power supplies is 12.7 volts.

R2 is therefore taking a current of 12.7 volts / 150 ohms = 84.7 mA. This current comes thru R1 as does the 50mA down the diode.

The rest is simple ohms law (and for you to figure out because this sounds like homework) and I get a value of R1 as 54.19 ohms.

Comment: How do you get 12.7 V forward? if the diode makes a 0.7 Voltage drop (since it requires 0.7 to fully open)? isnt that 12 - 0.7? It might sound like homework, but i am freely studying for my self, borrowed a book written in 1991 from the library.

Comment: @Mahitchima: The voltage at the anode must be higher than the voltage at the cathode in order for it to be considered "on".

Comment: The diode forward voltage adds to the 12V and not subtracts from it. Imagine a 14 ohm resistor in series with the 12 v supply. To get 50mA flowing (top to bottom) requires a voltage of 12.7 volts.

Comment: alright, so if i understand right, if the diode is coupled between +12V to ground, it is not forward biasing?

Comment: Oh, ok, yes ofcourse, i need the +12v to be negative in order for the diode to reverse-bias?

Comment: The 20V supply "defeats" the 12V supply and forward biases the diode. This is basic stuff and I can't spend much more time holding your hand until you understand. Try some web resources. You have your answer now do some leaning.

Comment: Yes, the +12V is negative with respect to the diode anode!

Comment: I have spent 3 days, trying to understand this circuit andy, i've used several resources, and all of them told me nothing, but now i feel i might be on to something., so thank you for the answer !

Comment: if 20V forward biases the diode, it looses 12+0.7volts = 7.3 Volts. so the voltage through R1 is 7.3 Volts? 

And +12V cannot reverse-bias, so Ground needs to be -12.7 Volts so the difference is +0.7, just enough to make the diode conduct?  I must be totaly blind.. this book does not explain anything about what happens, neither has a formula map, so it get's hard to understand, badly written.

Comment: Yes there is 7.3 volts across R1 and there is diode current (50mA) plus R2 current flowing thru it. 12.7 volts is across R2 therefore you know R2 current......

Comment: Interesting, i did not understand this until i played a little, cause 20 - 12 = 8 - 0.7 = 7.3, the 20V is split between the resistors, so 20 - 7.3 = 12.7V continues on over R2 to ground, Therefore 12.7 Volts, explained in a simple matter?

Answer (score 0):

The voltage over D and E is 12V + 0.7V = 12.7V (forward voltage of the diode).
Then you know the voltage over R2 which is 12.7V and so you can calculate the current trough it. Which is I=12.7V/150Ohm = 0.08466A.
Now you can calculate the total current trough R1 which is Id+I2= 0.13466A
The voltage over R1 is 20V-12.7V = 7.3V.
The resistance of R1=U/I = 7.3V/0.13466A = 54.2 Ohm.
This value may be a little of due that I don't know which forward voltage is used in the book for D.

Comment: I am not quite shure i understand how you guys figure out that the forward voltage From E Reverse-Biasing D = 12 + 0.7V?

Comment: it's forward biased

Comment: so, it's the same as saying the negative side of the 12V -"battery" is -24.7, so the difference between them is 12.7 Volts? 

Do you have time, just to explain how you think, when you get the voltage over D and E = 12.7V. ? Because i need a reason why i should just take the Diode forward voltage + 12V and get the answer, not understanding really Why this happens.